# passing string as datetime parameter in sql command

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have dropdown combobox bound to a date field.

Now I want to pass the selected value in the combobox into a SQL query by using `SqlCommand`

I want to pass parameters & add with value in datetime.

I tried this code:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Expiry", cmbox.SelectedValue.ToString()); and also try
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Expiry", cmbExpiryDate.SelectedValue.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy"));
```

but no use it throw conversion overflow. I am beginner plz help me it is window form 
I am using 2005 studio

Value from combobox:
`28-04-2014 00:00:00`

**Error**
`Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime.`

Comment: what value is coming from your combobox, and what error are you getting?

Comment: value come in box is 28-04-2014 00:00:00 and error Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime.

Comment: using "sql querry is select* from tabl where exdate =@Expiry" in tabl exdate column is datetime

Comment: The SQL Server format is YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS

Comment: can i use cmbExpiryDate.SelectedValue.ToString("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS")

Comment: it shows string overflow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many formats supported by SQL Server - see the [MSDN Books Online on CAST and CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx). Most of those formats are **dependent** on what settings you have - therefore, these settings might work some times - and sometimes not.

The way to solve this is to use the (slightly adapted) **ISO-8601 date format** that is supported by SQL Server - this format works **always** - regardless of your SQL Server language and dateformat settings.

The [ISO-8601 format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180878.aspx) is supported by SQL Server comes in two flavors:

- `YYYYMMDD` for just dates (no time portion); note here: **no dashes!**, that's very important! `YYYY-MM-DD` is **NOT** independent of the dateformat settings in your SQL Server and will **NOT** work in all situations!

or:

- `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS` for dates and times - note here: this format *has* dashes (but they *can* be omitted), and a fixed `T` as delimiter between the date and time portion of your `DATETIME`.

This is valid for SQL Server 2000 and newer.

If you use SQL Server 2008 or newer and the `DATE` datatype (only `DATE` - **not** `DATETIME`!), then you can indeed also use the `YYYY-MM-DD` format and that will work, too, with any settings in your SQL Server.

Don't ask me why this whole topic is so tricky and somewhat confusing - that's just the way it is. But with the `YYYYMMDD` format, you should be fine for any version of SQL Server and for any language and dateformat setting in your SQL Server.

The recommendation for SQL Server 2008 and newer is to use DATE if you only need the date portion, and DATETIME2(n) when you need both date and time. You should try to start phasing out the DATETIME datatype if ever possible

Comment: Finally what should i do.If any modification in code required plz let me know

Comment: Use `SelectedValue.ToString("yyyyMMdd")`

Comment: it throws no overload for method "Tostring" takes one argument